# How to filter in dplyr based upon an associated condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame. I want to filter out some issues only in the case they are associated with a specific group.

For a dummy example, suppose I have the following:

```
> mydf
   Group Issue
1      A     G
2      A     H
3      A     L
4      B     V
5      B     M
6      C     G
7      C     H
8      C     L
9      C     X
10     D     G
11     D     H
12     D     I
```

I want to filter out rows with a "G" or "H" or "L" issue if there is also an "L" issue in that Group.

So in this case, I want to filter out rows 1, 2, 3, 6,7,8 but leave rows 4,5,9, 10,11, and 12. Thus the result would be:

```
> mydf
   Group Issue
4      B     V
5      B     M
9      C     X
10     D     G
11     D     H
12     D     I
```

I think I first need to `group_by(Group)` but then I'm wondering what's the best way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: @Frank -- good point. Let me rephrase to something a bit more like my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the rule is

> When a group contains L, drop L, G & H.

then

```
mydf %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  filter( if (any(Issue=="L")) !(Issue %in% c("G","H","L")) else TRUE )

#   Group Issue
# 1     B     V
# 2     B     M
# 3     C     X
# 4     D     G
# 5     D     H
# 6     D     I
```

Comment: Or `df %>% group_by(Group) %>% filter(!(any(Issue=="L") & (Issue %in% c("G","H","L"))))`